# A word for inverted requirements

Tags: single-word-requests

Say you have some condition that requires x, y, and z to be set for the condition to be true. These would be the 'required' senses

Is there a word for the inverse situation where a success condition requires all of x, y, and z must be unset? The 'inverted' requirements.
Preferrably something more intuitive than 'invert(ed)'

e.g. (X & Y & Z) vs !(X | Y | Z)

Comment: *inverse* or *complement*.   Potentially with the *bitwise* clarification   Also, your example is poor.  You can't negate just the logic as you show.  You are trying to say, X&Y&Z==~(X|Y|Z).  That is to say, you want to juxtapose 'all of' and 'none of'. Instead, ~(X&Y&Z) means 'not all of.'

Comment: in this way i'd agree, though arguably it's dependent on what the use case is

Answer (score 1):

I would say not, for two reasons:

1. The requirement that something be unset is still a requirement

And

2. It is possible to have a mixture of positive and negative requirements. That is (X & Y & !Z) to employ the notation you used. A familiar example would be X = engine running, Y = a gear engaged, Z = parking brake applied. If any one of the conditions (X), (Y) and (not Z) is untrue the car (with automatic transmission) won't go anywhere.

Comment: so.. are you saying to use the word "not" explicitly?

Comment: @CobaltHex  It depends, if you are writing for coders then the shriek or bang (!) will be interpreted as a negation, if not then it probably won't. Otherwise you could reformulate the condition the other way around (Z = "parking brake off" for instance) in which case all three of X, Y, and Z would need to be true for the car to move. Of course you could formulate the condition to include the negation (Z= parking brake not on) in which case  Z needs to be true as "not on" is the same as "off". It really depends what you're trying to say and, most importantly, in what context.

Comment: so i'm looking specifically for a word relating to the whole set.
The use case being I have a list of options to check off, and I want a duplicate list, but checking any of the items would be excluding. Looking for list headers

Answer (score 0):

[Dealbreaker](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/deal-breaker) might work:

> (in business and politics) a factor or issue which, if unresolved during negotiations, would cause one party to withdraw from a deal.

One site about [relationship advice](https://www.askingforwhatyouwant.com/deal-breakers-needs-and-desires/) notes that dealbreakers are requirements “flipped around”.